# Set Registry Keys from Domain Policy

Tags: active-directory, windows-registry

Is it possible to push out changes to the registry on a local computer from the domain policy?  Or does a special script need to be written to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly acceptable to use Group Policy to push out registry changes via Preferences as squillman mentioned.  Read up on Preferences before you start though, they don't behave in the same way as genuine Policies (sticky etc).  Also, there's a bit of getting around the correct syntax to use in the policy template - get it wrong and you'll be scratching your head for ages trying to figure it out.

Jon

Answer (score 0):

You can set registry keys via GPO prefence settings in a W2K8 domain. In a W2K3 domain you can only set security on registry keys via GPO, AFAIK.

Comment: -1 You can use the GPO preferences in a w2k3 domain.  You just need to install the client side extensions for older clients and have a Vista/Windows 7/W2k8 box with the gpmc installed to actually create/update the policies.

If you don't want to do the above you can always just create a policy that includes a startup/login script that updates the registry.